APEX Oracle filling the item with line values
I have an item of text type P_10_TEXTITEM. I would like to populate this item with values via SQL code, where each value would be on a new row. When I populate this item, nothing appears....
I have an item of text type and I would like to assign to it the line values via SQL code
    for row in (select EName, Comm from EMP
                 where instr( ':'||:P18_SHARED_SALESMAN||':',  ':'||EmpNo||':' ) > 0 )
    loop
          :P18_SHARED_NEW_COMMISSIONS := :P18_SHARED_NEW_COMMISSIONS || row.EName || ': ' || row.Comm || chr(13) || chr(10); 
     end loop;
    -- Step 5: Write the item values.
    :P18_SHARED_SALE_COMMISSION  := v_saleCommission;
    :P18_SHARED_COMMISSION_EACH  := v_commissionEach;


the variables are already displayed, but they do not line up


are you sure that select statement returns any values ? The where clause looks strange... what is the value of P18_EMPNO_SHARED ?

Please update the question with details on how you are populating the item. Where is is this code - is it a page process or a dynamic action ?

the variables are already displayed, but they do not line up... it is a page process..

That looks like a different issue from what you originally posted. You say the items are now displayed - what solved it ? Consider accepting the answer below if it helped - best way to thank the person that invested his time for you. For followup questions please post a new question.

I had the wrong variable name in the where condition, thank you.. so I'll post a new question for this new display problem

Great thanks for the update - this can benefit others

You didn't say how exactly you're doing that; what is row? How are local variables declared?
Anyway: using Scott's sample schema, my FOR cursor loop populates Textarea item with employees and their jobs. To do that, I created a Page Load dynamic action:
begin
  :P2_TEXT := null;
  
  for cur_r in (select ename, job from emp where deptno = 20) loop
    :P2_TEXT := :P2_TEXT || cur_r.ename ||', '|| cur_r.job || chr(13);
  end loop;
end;

Have a look at screenshot which shows both dynamic action and output:


I fill the variable in the process after pressing the button,I added the code I use

OK; so adjust code I posted so that it works on your side (just like it works on mine).
